# Why the Javascript does not run?

Tags: javascript, html

I am a newbie in web development and tried my hand the following code:

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>A Generic Page </title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        setTimeOut(wakeUpUser, 5000);
        function wakeUpUser() {
            alert("Time to make life interesting");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
         <h1>Just a generic heading </h1>
         <p>Just  a normal paragraph</p>
    </body>
  </html>
```

But the script does not run only a boring static HTML page.I am following the HeadFirst Javascript Programming.Is the book wrong on this example?

Comment: Try `setTimeout`, JS is case sensitive

Comment: Wait until you learn your Elements are undefined, unless you use an `onload` Event in your head. Just another tip, before you have to ask that question too.

Comment: **browser developer tools** - use them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the Script error in your code, modify the "**SetTimeout**" to an actual case.
I have attached both the result of your code and Bug Fixed code results, where SetTimeout code fix suggested works fine.

```
setTimeout(wakeUpUser, 5000);
```

**Your Code Before Fix:**
[image: Code with Script Error]

**Result After Bug Fix:**

[image: Working Code]

Comment: I like to highlight that error view in the Browser is using "Developer Tools" of the chrome browser, which can be displayed using "F12" key press in the browser and the same F12 key will hide the developer tools option in the browser.

Comment: Thanks, @NirmalGoswami, which can be easily understood by beginner just by seeing images.

Answer (score 5):

You have a typo in your JavaScript. `setTimeout` should be written with a small "o".

Answer (score 1):

Just a super small typo in your code, instead of 'setTimeOut', it needs to be a lowercase 'O', so 'setTimeout'. Here's the complete snippet:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>A Generic Page </title>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      setTimeout(wakeUpUser, 5000);
      function wakeUpUser() {
         alert("Time to make life interesting");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Just a generic heading </h1>
    <p>Just  a normal paragraph</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you much call **setTimeout** use **o** insteh of **O** after declare function :) ... If you don't have jQuery library. try to use **setInterval** function :) more exaple

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: What does jQuery have to do with anything? Why would they want to use setInterval here?

Comment: Nope, I mean setTimeout function is not 1 solution for auto call a function after a long time. setInterval is orther function for doing that :)

Answer (score -2):

Try moving the setTimeout to be after the function is declared.

Your browser's developer tools should show you any errors encountered. Specifically the 'console'.

Happy coding!

Edit: see also the other answers about the small o in setTimeout